# C++ pointer member initialization

Tags: c++, object, pointers, scope, new-operator

I know this is really basic, but I don't know the answer given my very limited C++ usage.

I was told whenever a class contains a pointer as a member, I should allocate memory for it. (and then use 'delete' inside the destructor to free the space)

```
class Person{
    public:
    string* ptr_name;
    Person(string& name){
        ptr_name = new string(name);
    }
...
}
```

I was thinking if I can just do this instead

```
class Person{
    public:
    string* ptr_name;
    Person(string name){
        ptr_name = &name;
    }
...
}
```

As I didn't use '&' inside the constructor argument, 'name' is copied by value inside the constructor. So memory is already allocated for it. The explicit destructor will be unnecessary since the pointer will be automatically destroyed on stack.

Would this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After calling this constructor

```
Person(string name){
    ptr_name = &name;
}
```

the pointer `ptr_name` will be invalid because the local variable `name` will be destroyed.

Thus dereferencing such a pointer will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well. But I cannot get an error case to demonstrate this. Would you suggest any?

Comment: @yuhao Undefined behavior means that anything can occur even you can get the expected result. Try for example this code         class Person {
        public:
            std::string *ptr_name;
            Person( std::string name ) {
                ptr_name = &name;
            }
        };

        Person person( "Hello" );

        std::cout << *person.ptr_name << '\n';

Comment: I agree with you and have tried on a wrapper class on string to show 'name' does get destroyed as constructor finish, so I think &name should not be used. Weirdly, the test case just 10 out of 10 times returns 'Hello' for me, very different from other undefined behaviors I encountered. Thanks.